# Socket.io nginx Redis - Client not receiving messages from server

Tags: nginx, laravel-5, socket.io, node-redis

I'm quite confused. I was testing this application on localhost with Mamp and everything was working fine but when moved to the development server the client stop receiving messages from server. I'm using it inside a Vuejs component.

On the client I've logged `socket.on('connect')` and the second check is returning true.

This is my code:

**Server**

```
var server = require ('http').Server();
var io = require ('socket.io')(server);
var Redis = require ('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();


redis.subscribe('chat');

redis.on('message', (channel, message) => {
  message = JSON.parse(message);

  // channel:event:to_id:to_type - message.data
  io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event + ':' + message.to_id + ':' + message.to_type, message.data);
  console.log(message +' '+ channel);
});

server.listen('6001');
```

**Client**

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:6001', {reconnect: true});
...
mounted() {
    console.log('check 1', socket.connected);
    socket.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('check 2', socket.connected);
    });

    socket.on('chat:newMessage:'+this.fromid+':'+this.fromtype, (data) => {
      console.log('new message');
      var message = {
        'msg': data.message,
        'type': 'received',
        'color': 'green',
        'pos': 'justify-content-start',
      }
      this.messages.push(message);
    });
}
```

**Nginx conf**

```
upstream node1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:6001;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        #Configure proxy to pass data to upstream node1
        proxy_pass http://node1/socket.io/;
        #HTTP version 1.1 is needed for sockets
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found a solution.

I was using `localhost`

I've replaced

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:6001', {reconnect: true});
```

With:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://'+ window.location.hostname +':6001', {reconnect: true});
```

And now everything is working fine.